# ESelect and display png from custom folder

Tags: android

I've created a folder **'test'** inside **res** and I want to display them in an image view. How exactly can I fetch the image with a given name in the designated folder?

```
ImageView test = (ImageView) testing.findViewById(R.id.test);

flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().); <==== This?
```

**EDIT**

```
InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = this.getResources().getAssets().open("country_flags/sample.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ;
    }

    image = (ImageDrawable) BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);


    try {
        flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getAssets().open("country_flags/"+nationality+".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You can not access the folder. Consider using the `assets` folder instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How exactly can I fetch the image with a given name in the designated folder?

You don't. You cannot invent new resource types, and so your `test` directory will, at best, be forever ignored.

Comment: are you sure? So what is the best procedure is this scenario if I have a long list of images to include?

Comment: @Fane: "are you sure?" -- yes. In fact, I just tried it, and on Android Studio having a `res/test/` directory with a PNG file in it fails to compile (which is what I expected). "So what is the best procedure is this scenario if I have a long list of images to include?" -- put them in an appropriate density edition of `res/drawable-NNNN/`. Or, put them in `assets/` and use `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` that you can pass to `BitmapFactory`.

Comment: @Having put it in assets, how can I turn it into a imagedrawable? I have this (see edit)

Comment: @Fane: As I wrote, use `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` that you can pass to `BitmapFactory`. `BitmapFactory` has `decodeStream()` methods that will give you `Bitmap` objects back, which you can pass to your `ImageView`.